# Floating Point IEE754

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I am trying to convert: 1.6180339887 to the IEE754 Floating Point Form. As a binary, I got 1.10011110001101111, and therefore for my exponent I got 158. When checking on an online calculator, the answer keeps coming up as 127 as the exponent. I am wondering if I perhaps missed a step.

Comment: Why do you think the exponent would be 158?

Answer (score 0):

Your number decodes as a single-precision float as:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 01111111 10011110001101110111101
             Hex: 3FCF 1BBD
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: 0 (Stored: 127, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: +0x1.9e377ap0
           Value: +1.618034 (NORMAL)
```

and as a double precision float as:

```
                  6    5          4         3         2         1         0
                  3 21098765432 1098765432109876543210987654321098765432109876543210
                  S ----E11---- ------------------------F52-------------------------
          Binary: 0 01111111111 1001111000110111011110011011100101001000011011100101
             Hex: 3FF9 E377 9B94 86E5
       Precision: DP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: 0 (Stored: 1023, Bias: 1023)
       Hex-float: +0x1.9e3779b9486e5p0
           Value: +1.6180339887 (NORMAL)
```

So, in neither case the exponent is 158. If you can tell us how you computed the exponent, we can help identify where you went wrong!